# Как оптимизировать код плеера?

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте, епть код плеера радио, который подгружает данные о текущем треке из файла спомощью php, который берет данные из текстового файла.

Но плеер расположен на большом количестве сайтов, что часто вызывает большую нагрузку.

Возможно ли как-то оптимизировать работу и уменьшить нагрузку?

**Код плеера js:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var player_default = "GTI Radio";
    var player_loading = "Идёт загрузка...";
    var player_ready = false;
    var player_stream_default = 1;
    var player_streams = [{
        title: "96",
        mp3: "http://radio.globaltranceinvasion.com:8000/radiolow"
    }, {
        title: "128",
        mp3: "http://radio.globaltranceinvasion.com:8000/radiomid"
    }, {
        title: "256",
        mp3: "http://radio.globaltranceinvasion.com:8000/radiohi"
    }, {
        title: "320",
        mp3: "http://radio.globaltranceinvasion.com:8000/radio320"
    }];

    $(document).ready(function () {

        function getStreamSong() {

            $.ajax({

                url: "http://player.gtiradio.ru/count.php",

                cache: false,

                success: function (html) {

                    $(".song").html(html);

                }
            });

        }

        function setRadioPlay() {
            getStreamSong();
            radioSongUpdate = setInterval(getStreamSong, 20000);
        }

        function setRadioStop() {
            clearInterval(radioSongUpdate);
        }

        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function (event) {
                player_ready = true;
                $(this).jPlayer('setMedia', player_streams[player_stream_default]);
            },
            pause: function () {
                $(this).jPlayer('clearMedia');
                $('#player .song').text(player_default);
                setRadioStop();
            },
            error: function (event) {
                if (player_ready && event.jPlayer.error.type === $.jPlayer.error.URL_NOT_SET) {
                    $('#player .song').html(player_loading);
                    $(this).jPlayer('setMedia', player_streams[player_stream_default]).jPlayer('play');
                    setRadioPlay();
                } else {
                    $('#player .song').text(player_default);
                    setRadioStop();
                }
            },
            swfPath: "jsplayer",
            supplied: "mp3",
            solution: "html, flash",
            preload: "none",
            wmode: "window",
            keyEnabled: true
        });
        $('#player .streams a').bind('click', function () {
            var key = $(this).attr('data-stream');
            player_stream_default = key;

            $('#player .song').html(player_loading);
            $('#player .streams a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

            $('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('clearMedia');

            $('#player .song').html(player_loading);
            $('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('setMedia', player_streams[player_stream_default]).jPlayer('play');
            setRadioPlay();

            return false;
        });
        var mPlayer = $("#jquery_jplayer_1"),
            options = {
                volumechange: function (event) {
                    if (event.jPlayer.options.muted) {
                        myControl.volume.slider("value", 0);
                    } else {
                        myControl.volume.slider("value", event.jPlayer.options.volume);
                    }
                },
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
            }
        myControl = {
            volume: $(options.cssSelectorAncestor + " .jp-volume-slider")
        };
        $('.jp-gui ul li').hover(
            function () {
                $(this).addClass('u-state-hover');
            },
            function () {
                $(this).removeClass('u-state-hover');
            }
        );
        myControl.volume.slider({
            animate: "fast",
            max: 1,
            range: "min",
            step: 0.01,
            value: $.jPlayer.prototype.options.volume,
            superslide: function (event, ui) {
                mPlayer.jPlayer("option", "muted", false);
                mPlayer.jPlayer("option", "volume", ui.value);
            }
        });

        $('#player a.jp-play').bind('click', function () {
            $('#player .song').html(player_loading);
            setRadioPlay();

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Код php:**

```
<?php 
    $str=file_get_contents('http://gtiradio.ru/player/nowplaying.txt');
    echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: кэшировать в статический файл.

Comment: как это реализовать*?

Comment: А каким образом все сайты связаны с источником треков? Что именно тормозит: сервер треков или js? С чего вы взяли что js тормозит?  Я бы даже сказал с уверенностью, что это не плеер тормозит. Т.к. в этом js просто описан конфиг для плеера. Какой у вас сервер?

Comment: да понятное дело не js. тут ничего не тормазит, просто фреймом вставляется плеер на другие сайты.

Comment: >  Да и не понятно что вообще за плеер у вас.

@Victor Halauko, обычный [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) же.

Comment: мне приходит отчет о нагрузке на сервер, что слошком много ресурсов уходит на работу файла http://player.gtiradio.ru/count.php он как раз достает название трека из файла http://gtiradio.ru/player/nowplaying.txt

Возможно ли как-то оптимизировать работу чтобы нагрузки было меньше...

Comment: А хостинг за 2$ в месяц?

"обычный jPlayer же." @Nofate, на такой ответ - следующий ответ, обычная я же оптимизация )) @Alexander Sizintsev, так а источник какой? Ваш сервер? Или вы вставляете код со стороннего ресурса?

Comment: А зачем вы держите названия треков в файле? Mysql в сотни раз быстрее будет работать при большом количестве треков!!!!
Уверен, что у вас там десятки тысяч композиций, и php будет искать там нужную композицию очень долго! Как я понимаю вы импортируете файл с треками к себе на сайт. Так занесите все записи в бд. Любой трек будет искаться за тысячные доли секунды на нормальном сервере.

Comment: Наш сервер. С нашего сайта берут вставляют плеер радио на свои сайты. пример плеера http://player.gtiradio.ru/?id=standart его вставляют на сайт, когда люди врубают плеер то плеер обращается к файлу уже понятно какому, чтобы вывести название текущего трека. 

Возможно ли сделать оптимизацию и сделать работу подгрузки трека менее затратной по ресурсам?

Comment: код php этого файла ?

http://player.gtiradio.ru/count.php

так и сделайте 

http://gtiradio.ru/player/nowplaying.txt